# Solving a underdetermined equation system in Eigen (C++)

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, algebra, svd

In my case, I want to solve a underdetermined equation system, A*λ = b, with the *JacobiSVD* solver from Eigen (3.0.12).

The linear equation system has following structure in my C++ program:

Coefficient matrix (**A**):

```
       0.6           5.68434e-20      -0.2
       5.68434e-20   7.06819e-39      -4.26326e-20
       -0.2          -4.26326e-20     0.4
```

RHS (**b**):

```
       -1.962
       2.78817e-19
       -5.886
```

**Lambda**:

```
       -9.81
       3.94467e+19         <---------- error (Where does this come from?)
       -19.62
```

- The rank of matrix A is - **Rank(A) = 2**
- So the matrix has No Full rank. Therefore, A is singular and not invertible.
- The condition is - **cond(A) = Inf**
- For solving A*λ = b, I used the **SVD** decomposition method from Eigen (JacobiSVD)

I also verified this with MATLAB:
http://www.pictureupload.us/image-172220092351c5ae0c1706e.htm

On begin, the first simulation steps are approximatley correct. But there is a very small numerical error, which is increasing during solving A*λ = b.

Then the system is crashing and my results are not anymore correct and I get NaN results.

Here the code:

```
/******** SVD ********/
JacobiSVD<TMatrixX> svd(A, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
lambda = svd.solve(b);
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

JacobiSVD considers all non-zeros singular values for solving. I recommend using ColPivHouseholderQR.